# Python tkinter change individual button parameters created in for loop

Tags: python, loops, button, for-loop, tkinter

Hi I have created 15 buttons using a for loop, each button passes a name and opens a new top level window, within the top level window there are 2 more buttons, one called 'clock in' and the 'clock out' I want to change the background of the initial button (the one with the name in it) based on whether somebody clocks in or out, however i have no idea how to address individual buttons created in a for loop.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry('800x480+0+0')
master.title('Gateway Logger')

names = ['Annette', 'Heather', 'Tracey', 'Amy', 'Josh', 'Chris'
         , 'Lekh', 'Ellie', 'Sarah', 'Richard', 'Paula', 'Michelle'
         , 'Martin', 'Dave', 'Phil']
visitors = ['Visitor 1', 'Visitor2', 'Visitor 3', 'Visitor 4', 'Visitor 5', 'Visitor 6']

name_width = 20
name_height = 5
xpad = 5
ypad = 5
col = 0
roww = 0

sarah='out'

def clock_mast(n):
    iowid=40
    iohi=15
    global clock
    print "This is: " +str(n)
    clock = Toplevel(width=300, height =300)
    clock.title('Clock In/Out')

    staff_name = Label (clock, text = n, font = "Verdana 24")
    staff_name.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=2)

    inbut=Button(clock, width=iowid, height=iohi, text='Clock In', bg='green',command=lambda:clock_in())
    inbut.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10,pady=50, columnspan=1)
    outbut=Button(clock, width=iowid, height=iohi, text='Clock Out', bg='red',command=lambda:clock_out())
    outbut.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10,pady=50, columnspan=1)



def clock_in():
    global clock
    clock.destroy()

def clock_out():
    global clock
    clock.destroy()


for n in names:  
    b = Button(master,text=n,width = name_width, height = name_height,command=lambda n=n: clock_mast(n))
    b.grid(row = roww, column = col,padx = xpad, pady = ypad)
    col += 1
    if col == 3:
        col = 0
        roww += 1



master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current program is that in the `for` loop you are actually over-writing previously created buttons when you are creating a new button, so its not possible to access them anymore (since there is no reference remaining to those buttons in your script).

I would advice that you can create a dictionary and store the buttons with the `n` (names) as the key, and then pass the name of the parent button to `clock_in()` and `clock_out()` functions and then use that name to get the reference to the button and configure its properties.

Example code -

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry('800x480+0+0')
master.title('Gateway Logger')

names = ['Annette', 'Heather', 'Tracey', 'Amy', 'Josh', 'Chris'
         , 'Lekh', 'Ellie', 'Sarah', 'Richard', 'Paula', 'Michelle'
         , 'Martin', 'Dave', 'Phil']
visitors = ['Visitor 1', 'Visitor2', 'Visitor 3', 'Visitor 4', 'Visitor 5', 'Visitor 6']

name_width = 20
name_height = 5
xpad = 5
ypad = 5
col = 0
roww = 0

sarah='out'

def clock_mast(n):
    iowid=40
    iohi=15
    global clock
    print "This is: " +str(n)
    clock = Toplevel(width=300, height =300)
    clock.title('Clock In/Out')

    staff_name = Label (clock, text = n, font = "Verdana 24")
    staff_name.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=2)

    inbut=Button(clock, width=iowid, height=iohi, text='Clock In', bg='green',command=lambda n=n:clock_in(n))
    inbut.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10,pady=50, columnspan=1)
    outbut=Button(clock, width=iowid, height=iohi, text='Clock Out', bg='red',command=lambda n=n:clock_out(n))
    outbut.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10,pady=50, columnspan=1)



def clock_in(n):
    global clock
    global button_dict             #This is not really necessary, but I put it there to be explicit.
    button_dict[n].configure(bg='green')     #Choose whatever properties you want to choose to configure
    clock.destroy()

def clock_out(n):
    global clock
    global button_dict             #This is not really necessary, but I put it there to be explicit.
    button_dict[n].configure(bg='red')     #Choose whatever properties you want to choose to configure
    clock.destroy()

button_dict = {}

for n in names:  
    button_dict[n] = Button(master,text=n,width = name_width, height = name_height,command=lambda n=n: clock_mast(n))
    button_dict[n].grid(row = roww, column = col,padx = xpad, pady = ypad)
    col += 1
    if col == 3:
        col = 0
        roww += 1



master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I can't thank you enough, i would have never thought to do it that way! Exactly what i was looking for :-)